# Code For New Record/delete using tableadapter

Tags: vb.net

Instead of using the binding navigator, I would simply like to use buttons.

I'm familiar with the .Fill/.update etc... But what would create a new record?

Thanks!

Using:
Me.LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BCPM_DDBODataSet.LTC_FBS)
Me.LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Update(Me.BCPM_DDBODataSet.LTC_FBS)

Answer (score 0):

Created new insert query in table adapter and called it behind button's code:

Me.LTC_FBSTableAdapter.FillInsert(Me.BCPM_DDBODataSet.LTC_FBS)

where fillinsert is the name of the insert query i created.